# Is there a logging system for bitcoind, and if so then where is the log?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

Where and what is the name of log files of bitcoind?

If I make a command like "sendtoaddress", will the command and the arguments (like the amount of bitcoin I sent and which address I sent) all be logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default data location of bitcoind is ~/.Bitcoin on unix and %APPDATA%\Bitcoin on windows. In it, bitcoind will write a debug.log file which is automatically trimmed every once in a while. I'm not sure what is in it, but it should be easy to check. You can also start bitcoind with a commandline parameter to send its debug info to stdout, if you wish.